# Concurrent access to OpenCL kernel parameter value

Tags: concurrency, opencl, arguments

I'm working of parallel application, and I would like to ask one question, because I'm little confuse. When I have 100 instances of kernel and I would like to sell them the value, which will be for every kernel the same. Must I have an array of same 100 values (for each kernel one), or good enough for me just one value for all kernel. If I use a single value, will be maintained concurrent access to this value? The value is for read only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if you can pass a scalar as a read-only argument to a kernel launched via `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()`, like this:

```
__kernel void kerncode(int cval,.....) { ... };
.
.
.
int magiconstant = 1234567;
clSetKernelArg(kerncode, 0, sizeof(int),(void*)&magiconstant);
.
.
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kerncode, ...);
```

then the answer yes, of course you can.

Comment: If I doit like you write, then the value will be stored in private memory?
And what when I doit like this:
**__kernel void kerncode(__local int cval,.....) { ... };**
will be maintained concurrent access for read to this value in block of work-items?

Comment: I don't believe you can use __local memory like that - it is not possible to initialize __local memory outside of a kernel..

Comment: Local memory can definitely not be used for that purpose. Local memory can only be allocated from outside, but can not be written from host. The best way to use scalars was mentioned by talonmies. Global memory is too slow. The constant memory is maybe suitable, as long as the constant has a global nature during a lot of calculations.